# Prove $\sin(1/n)<1/n$ for all $n$

Tags: induction

I need to prove $\sin(1/n)<1/n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ using mathematical induction.

Dont know how to start. Please help!

Comment: Starting is the easy part! Base case: $n=1$
$$\sin \left(1\over 1\right)<1 \, \color{green}\checkmark$$

Comment: Why did you take it so literally?

Comment: Because he is a mathematician.

Comment: What makes you think induction is a good approach to this problem?

Comment: @mopdf [Boys will be boys](http://s24.postimg.org/cuhpnohn9/way_of_life.jpg).

Comment: (You can easily show $\sin(x)<x$ for all positive $x$ using the Taylor series for $\sin$.)

Comment: @GitGud +1 for the comic and +1 to potato...exactly what I was going to say but you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @mopdf Are you allowed to use both induction and calculus?

Comment: Or you could show that $(x-\sin(x))' = 1-\cos(x) \geq 0$ and $>0$ in some neighborhood of $0$... It is not induction of course.

Comment: I'd like to see how to use both induction and calculus on this problem. If appropiate, a hint would be fine. Thank you all.

Comment: @mopdf Well, just use Potato's comment above. You don't need induction. But since you're required to use it, use it! I mean, do the base case, then assume the induction hypothesis and prove what you want. You won't need to use the induction hypothesis, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it that way. Thanks Git Gud.

Comment: @FixedPoint It may not have been clear, but that comic is part of a book called [Logicomix: An Epic Search for Truth](http://www.amazon.com/Logicomix-Search-Truth-Apostolos-Doxiadis/dp/1596914521).

Comment: @Potato "(You can easily show sin(x)<x for all positive x using the Taylor series for sin.)"... If $x\leqslant\sqrt{20}$, I see how to do it. But for higher values of $x$...

Comment: @Did Well, considering $|\sin(x)|\le 1$, that doesn't seem to present much of a problem.

Comment: @Did (I think I'm missing some extremely dry humor here. If so, my apologies.)

Comment: @Potato No humor here, neither dry nor wet, just wondering what you meant by "using the Taylor series". Can you explain the argument showing that `sin x < x` **using the Taylor series**? The argument which uses `|sin x| < 1` to get rid of higher values of `x` is different.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry if I was unclear. Small values of $x$ can be eliminated using the Taylor series as in Dominic's answer below. The bound for larger values follows from $\sin$ being bounded in magnitude by $1$.

Comment: @Potato OK. Then two different arguments it is (as hypothesized in my first comment), the one in your comment for small values and another one for large values. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Because of 
\[ \sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!} +\dots \]
As $x^n$ is monotone decreasing on $[0,1]$ in respect to $n$. Hence 
\[ \sin(x)\leq x \] for $x$ in $[0,1]$.  As $\sin(x)\leq 1$ the inequality is even 
true for all $x\in [0,\infty)$.

We can see that when $x-\sin(x)> 0$ holds for $x\in (0,1]$ this implies that $\sin\big(\frac{1}{n}\big) < \frac{1}{n}$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
At first we note that for $x=0$ $\sin(x)-x=0$. The derivative of 
\[ x - \sin(x)\]
is $1-\cos(x)$. With the fundamental theoroem of calculus we know that 
\[ x-\sin(x) = (1-\cos(\xi)) \cdot x \] 
where $\xi \in (0,x)$. As $\cos (x) \leq 1$ and $x>0$ we have that $x-\sin(x)$ is positive and hence our inequality holds.

Comment: For some reason OP wants or needs to prove this by induction...

Comment: @Martin in the comments he said he like both the induction and the calculus on the problem. But I have no hope for a useful induction proof

Comment: Okay, in that case I would simply develop the Taylor series up to degree 5 and use that the series alternates and the terms are monotonically decreasing. This allows you to avoid the mean value theorem.

Comment: @Martin I made 2 proofs :)

Comment: Oh, I should have looked closer. I took the second part to be dealing with establishing the strict inequality asked in the OP :)

Comment: "for $x$ in $[0,\infty)$" >> "for $x$ in $[0,1)$".

Comment: @Did Is there something wrong? I edited how to come from $[0,1]$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: No. And it reads better now.